# Eigenvalues order in conics reduction?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I'm doing exercises on the reductions of conics to canonic forms using eigenvalues. I'm trying to understand what does actually change when I put the two eigenvalues that I find in a different order

For example:

$\mathscr{C} : x^2-xy+\frac{1}{4}y^2-2x+6y+6=0$

is a parabola and the matrix $A$ associated to it has eigenvalues $0$ and $\frac{5}{4}$

To reduce the conic I have to choose the order of the eigenvalues to put in the reduced form and the first eigenvalue is the coefficient of the $x^2$ term so in one case the parabola will have only the $x^2$ and in the other only the $y^2$

Does this make any difference? Is there a particolar order that must be followed? Is the conic just rotated in two different ways?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Consider a parabola of equation $y=ax^2$. If you rotate coordinate axes of $\pi/2$ the equation becomes $x=-ay^2$, because the axes get interchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the quadratic terms are $(2x-y)^2/4$, which you can rewrite as $u^2/4$. There is no choice between $x$ or $y$, this is a new coordinate.

The rotation is unambiguously defined by $u=2x-y$.